# How can I tell if the user tries to close the window in C++?

Tags: c++, allegro

I need to break a while loop when the use clicks the close button on the window, but I don't know what to check for. I'm using allegro to run the GUI.

Comment: What platform/GUI library are you talking about?

Comment: It's very important to give more information or the question will be closed as 'Not a real question'

Comment: @Oli: I'm using allegro.

Comment: Do you use such: http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_-_A_Game_Programming_Library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Allegro 4: [set_close_button_callback](http://www.allegro.cc/manual/4/api/using-allegro/set_close_button_callback)()

```
volatile int hit_closed = 0;

void close_button_proc()
{
  hit_closed = 1;
}

// later after creating the display:

set_close_button_callback(close_button_proc);

while (!hit_closed)
{
}
```

With Allegro 5, it's more like:

```
al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));

// in your event loop:

if (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE) {
}
```

See [the manual](http://www.allegro.cc/manual) for all the details.